# How can I view web pages through SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh

In case there are four machines with their ip:

```
machine A : 192.168.1.1
machine B : 10.25.1.1
machine C : 10.25.1.34
machine D : 172.16.1.1
```

In machine D, I can connect to A. After I log in A, I can ssh to the other
three machines but D and B,C cannot communicate each other.
B and C host web pages. Now I want to view web pages in B from machine D.

So, I decide to use SSH tunnel in machine B,

```
me@B> ssh *:80:localhost:80 me@192.168.1.1
```

Then, I log in A, open browser, type `http://127.0.0.1`.
It correctly forwards to `10.25.1.1`, page appears, everything seems fine.
But in A, type `http://192.168.1.1`, it forwards to `12.25.1.34` oddly and
page appears. What happened under the hood ?

Finally, in machine D, type `http://192.168.1.1` in browser, the url successfully
jumps to `12.25.1.34` but which is not expected. It should be `12.25.1.1`. Wait for
a while, the browser says it cannot display the page. Strange! How can I view web
pages which comes from B in D ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the above solution cannot work. Following method works well.

```
me@D> ssh 8080:localhost:8181 me@192.168.1.1

me@A> ssh 8181:localhost:80 me@10.25.1.1
```